# How to handle developer errors in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I have to differentiate between operational and programmer(developer) errors. All errors with `stack` property are marked as developer errors. I log them and crash the server.

My question is if this approach will correctly identify all programmers errors (tried to read property of "undefined", called an asynchronous function without a callback, passed a "string" where an object or int was expected etc.)

Here is my error handler:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // Delegate to the default Express error handler,
  // when the headers have already been sent to the client
  if (res.headersSent) return next(err);

  // Decorate with additional properties from Boom
  // If err has no specified status code or there is a stack, it is most likely a programmer error.
  // Server must crash and restart. Default error code is set to 'Internal Server Error (500)'
  const options = err.stack || !err.statusCode
    ? { data: { stack: err.stack || 'n/a', developerError: true } }
    : {};
  if (!err.isBoom) boom.boomify(err, options);

  // Add more details
  const message = {
    ...err,
    originalUrl: req.originalUrl,
    method: req.method,
    ip: req.ip
  };

  // Log server errors only. No need to log 402, 403 etc.
  if (err.isServer) winston.error(message);

  // Crash server in case of a developer error.
  // NOTE: a Node.js process manager should be set up to immediately restart the crashed server
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-process-exit
  if (err.data && err.data.developerError) process.exit(1);

  return res.status(err.output.statusCode).json(message);
});
```

Comment: interesting code...could you post a minimal runnable example? I don't think you can catch all errors like this but's still, it looks nice.

Comment: @mihai Here is the implementation which I believe should handle all errors. https://github.com/sandorTuranszky/production-ready-expressjs-server 

And here is a short wiki on error handling I implemented https://github.com/sandorTuranszky/production-ready-expressjs-server/wiki/Error-handling